# iOS AutoLayout - when does it Run?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a XIB file where I specify constraints at design time.
In addition to controls with constraints, I also have controls that have no constraints in the XIB that I want to position programmatically at run time.

I do this by repositioning views manually in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

When I rotate the device, my code places the controls that are manually controlled but then later it appears that auto layout messes up the placement of manual controls that have no constraints on them in the Interface builder.

Question - When exactly does Auto layout run if I rotate the device.

Comment: It appears that somehow the position of a control that I am attempting to manually change in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is being overwritten by the position specified for that control in the XIB file.  Note that this control has no constraints associated with it.

So the question is - what would force it to load the position from the XIB after I have manually changed it in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: The default constraints. Try `NSLog(@"%@", control.constraints)` and similarly on the control's superview and see.

Answer (score 1):

Auto Layout runs at the end of the run loop after `setNeedsLayout` is called on a view, or immediately when `setNeedsLayout` is followed by `layoutIfNeeded`. Note that there are many methods that may call `setNeedsLayout` in their implementation, such as `addSubview:`, `removeFromSuperview`, etc.

A couple suggestions:

Instead of updating your constraints in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, try doing so in `updateViewConstraints`.

You may also want to add placeholder constraints in Interface Builder to the views you will position programmatically. I think IB will automatically constrain views to their x/y position if a placeholder constraint is not set, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to know is that the *results* of constraint calculations are applied in `layoutSubviews`. So if you want to set frames, you do so after calling `super` in `layoutSubviews` or in your view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Having said that, I've only experimented with this. I've not done it in production code and can't say that you won't run into issues.

I'm actually not clear on whether it's OK to set frames manually like this. The only relevant bit of information I've come across is the following from Apple's [Auto Layout documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutConcepts/AutoLayoutConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH14-SW1):

> You cannot set a constraint to cross the view hierarchy if the
>   hierarchy includes a view that sets the frames of subviews manually in
>   a custom implementation for the layoutSubviews method on UIView (or
>   the layout method on NSView).

Here, the phrase "view that sets the frames of subviews manually" implies to me that manually setting frames is OK. I'd be interested to know if anyone has a see a more explicit discussion on this.

Comment: Isn't it advisable to avoid directly setting frames when using Auto Layout?

Comment: @Austin I'm not too clear on that, so I updated my answer a bit. The poster did specifically say he wanted to position views manually.

Comment: Ah, I took "position programmatically" to mean, "position programmatically with constraints"

Answer (score 0):

you must not change the frame you must connect the constraint with iboulet and in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation you can change the constraint like this:

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(fromInterfaceOrientation)) {
      self.constraintTop.constant = 50;
  }else{
      self.constraintTop.constant = 100;
  }
  }